# I have defined a variable inside a function, but its not working in the output. attached the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Im defining a function where the sentence of user inputs, which starts from how, what, when should automatically get "?" at the end of the sentence in output. and rest should be with "."

Now my question is in the 4th line if statement. Here instead of caps if i replace it with phrase, i get the right result, else the 5th line is not taking effect in the output and the result will be by default with"." at the end of the user input.

I have called and defined the "phrase" in the variable caps. `caps = phrase.capitalize()` Now why cant i directly call caps as in the below statement. If I run the program as it is then for all the output irrespective to how, what, when its giving the output with the sentence ending"."

My Error Program:

```
def sent(phrase):
    a = ("how", "what", "when")
    caps = phrase.capitalize()
    if caps.startswith(a):
        return "{}?".format(caps)
    else:
        return "{}.".format(caps)

userinput = input("Say something: ")
print(sent(userinput))
```

Correct code for the required output is as below:

```
def sent(phrase):
    a = ("how", "what", "when")
    caps = phrase.capitalize()
    if phrase.startswith(a):
        return "{}?".format(caps)
    else:
        return "{}.".format(caps)

userinput = input("Say something: ")
print(sent(userinput))
```

Comment: Well think about it, after you've capitalised "how now brown cow" *does* it start with "how"?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `startswith()` is case sensitive. You are checking if the text starts with the word `how` but your text after capitalizing starts with `How` not `how`. So what you can do is check first and then capitalize.